# what does my work admin see on my pc and phone?

Tags: security, internet, administrator, sophos

I have a computer in my office connected to .Net server of the work place. Plus the whole internet in the place also needed to be accessed by a valid user account. They use a technology called sophos ( Either personaldevice to use wifi or the place's computer.

My questions are: what exactly can they see? Do they see my computer as if the watch a TV or it is only text records of what I do?  Do they also record websites I enter from personal devices?  What can I do to avoid monitoring ? Knowing that no vpn app or proxy site is working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sophos will show what applications are installed/actively running on your computer, who is logged in, and a history of sites visited. Generally your computer can't be viewed live unless someone takes remote control, and you would know if that happened, you'll either be logged off, or receive a notification. What you type isn't being recorded. It's very unlikely that you're just being "watched", speaking as someone who has spent a long time in I.T., we generally only setup filters to stop people on corporate networks from viewing porn, beyond that we couldn't care less what people are looking at :P Usually the concern is more focused on mitigating viruses from entering the network, which is really what sophos excels at, it's not really a great "spy" tool, if you will.

Answer (score 1):

> what exactly can they see? Do they see my computer as if the watch a TV or it is only text records of what I do?

The simple answer is: it's *their* PC, they can see, read, hear, trace, log, record, audit and modify anything and everything in any way they want. Whether they *actually* do that is something only they know. (And whether that is legal depends on your jurisdiction. In many jurisdictions, an employee has little privacy when using work devices or work networks.)

> Do they also record websites I enter from personal devices?

As to your phone: they can't see anything on your phone (unless you installed some additional remote management software), but they can see all network traffic. Again, it's *their* network, they can do, see, read, log, monitor, audit, and record anything and everything.

Again, whether they *actually* do that, only they know.

> What can I do to avoid monitoring ?

Don't use company property (devices or networks) for private stuff.

Comment: That is slightly contradictory to DivXZero answer. Are you sure they can see read and open the files you are opening?

Comment: They own the PC. They can do, read, see, install, run, log, record, modify, hear, and trace anything they want.